# How do i make a 3d model of this logo

Tags: modeling

I am trying to turn this logo into a 3d model, but no matter how I try i cant really figure it out. I am quite new to blender, so excuse my lack of knowledge, but i first tried adding shapes above the image (reference) and trying to re-create it. I came to an issue though with the curves. I was able to manage the circles in the middle, but the other curves, I cant figure out. How do I create "curved" objects such as the ones in the logo so that I can pretty much recreate the logo.

The logo I am trying to recreate:
[image: The logo I am trying to recreate]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Could you show your result and better explain where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Just trace the logo on a vector graphics program like Inkscape, illustrator or similar, exprort the paths as SVG, import into blender and give it some extrusion and material.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to recreate the shape, you should begin this way:

- Load your image as a background in the 3D view <kbd>N</kbd> panel.

[image]

- As your logo is made of concentric circles, create a circle and extrude it inwards.

[image]

- Delete all the useless faces.

[image]

- Create some new circles for the rest of the shape.

[image]

- Again, delete the useless faces, then join the meshes with some merges (<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>).

[image]

- Move some edges to stick to the logo shape.

[image]

- Now you need to extrude on the Z axis to give your shape some thickness, create bevel, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much :)